# Issue with Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, gdb, segmentation-fault

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct Msg 
{
    MsgType msgType;
    INT   msgLen;
    VOID *pMessage;
    UINT No; 
}Msg;
```

I've defined a pointer:

```
Msg *startPointer = NULL;
```

Then I'm doing:

```
startPointer =  (Msg *)RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg;
```

Where

```
RX_BUFFER_STRUCT RxBufferArray[100];
```

And

```
typedef struct RX_BUFFER_STRUCT_T {
    UINT seqNum;
    Msg *IntMsg;
} RX_BUFFER_STRUCT;
```

Then I am doing:

```
temp = (U32 *)startPointer->pMessage;
```

Which gives me a segmentation fault. The value of RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg is 0x0 (from gdb), and trackSN is 1.

As soon as I hit the statement: **temp = (U32 *)startPointer->pMessage;**, when I try to print the value of startPointer->pMessage, it says: **Cannot access memory at address 0x8**

Any help in resolving the issue?

Comment: pointer is pointing to is not ensured.

Comment: Where have you initialized the array `RxBufferArray`? if you don't initialize, you will lead to such circumstances.

Comment: where are you allocating memory for `RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg` ?

Comment: Could anyone help me in initializing RxBufferArray or RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg? i just have the globally declared RX_BUFFER_STRUCT RxBufferArray[100]; statement. Also I am filling up RxBufferArray[ctxt.seqNum].IntMsg = temppIntMsg; in some other function. temppIntMsg is also of the same type "Msg" and have values filled up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct RX_BUFFER_STRUCT_T {
    UINT seqNum;
    Msg *IntMsg; //this is just pointer, no structure behind it
} RX_BUFFER_STRUCT;
```

You don't allocate memory for every "Msg" structure in your RX_BUFFER_STRUCT array.

I see two ways to solve it. All of them are based on programming principles you use.
First, if you just fill your "Msg" structure with data:

```
typedef struct RX_BUFFER_STRUCT_T {
    UINT seqNum;
    Msg IntMsg; //now this is not pointer, this is structure here
} RX_BUFFER_STRUCT;
```

And using:

```
startPointer =  (Msg *)&RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg; //I added "&" 
temp = (U32 *)startPointer->pMessage;
```

Second, when you get already filled structure:

```
typedef struct RX_BUFFER_STRUCT_T {
    UINT seqNum;
    Msg *IntMsg = 0; //this is still pointer
} RX_BUFFER_STRUCT;
```

Adding data:

```
Msg *tempMsg = (Msg*)calloc(sizeof(Msg));
memcpy(tempMsg, inputMsg, sizeof(Msg)); //inputMsg is pointer to filled structure
RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg = tempMsg;
```

Using data:

```
if(RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg == 0){
    return;
}else{
    startPointer =  (Msg *)RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg;
    temp = (U32*)startPointer->pMessage;
}
```

Now you first of all check if you have filled structure, then use data.

**UPD:** how to add data:

```
//global variables
int buffer_head = 0; //for writing
int buffer_tail = 0; //for reading
RX_BUFFER_STRUCT RxBufferArray[100];

void addData(Msg *inputMsg){
    Msg *tempMsg = (Msg*)calloc(sizeof(Msg));
    memcpy(tempMsg, inputMsg, sizeof(Msg)); //inputMsg is pointer to filled structure
    RxBufferArray[buffer_head++].IntMsg = tempMsg;
}

//main function for example
int main(){
    Msg message; //creates structure
    message.pMessage = calloc(30*sizeof(char)); //allocates memory for message string
    message.msgLen = sprintf((char*)message.pMessage, "Test message"); //fills message
    addData(&message); //adds message to buffer
return 0;
}
```

Comment: inputMsg is of what type and how to point it to the filled structure? Please hlep.

Comment: Thanks for the update. My question is, when u call the addData from main, does only one index of RxBufferArray will get updated? Or all the 100? I think only one, that is the 0th index. Is it? And when we try to dereference the index 1, the same thing as before (crash) happens?

Comment: Crash happened because "RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg" was pointing to nowhere. And when it pointing to nowhere, you cannot access it.

Comment: Crash happened because "RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg" was pointing to nowhere. And when it pointing to nowhere, you cannot access it.

Now we create some place to point and apply it to our pointer. We control that all filled structures located in 0.."buffer_head" cells. And even we want to access any random array cell, we check if "RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg" is correct pointer (not 0). 

With one addData we change content only of one cell in array, no all 100 cells. And if you want to read data from this array you have to accessa only 0..buffer_head cells. NOT higher than buffer_head.

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue, is there?

You say that the `IntMsg` is 0, so this:

```
 startPointer = (Msg *) RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg;
```

sets `startPointer` to 0. Then you de-reference that invalid pointer, causing undefined behavior (a segfault).

The mixing of types is very confusing, it's very hard to understand what you'er *trying* to achieve here, for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your structure:

```
typedef struct RX_BUFFER_STRUCT_T {
    UINT seqNum;
    Msg *IntMsg;
} RX_BUFFER_STRUCT;
```

When you declare an array of `RX_BUFFER_STRUCT`, It does not initialize the `IntMsg` pointer and the memory allocation for it should be done explicitly. This is the reason when you try to refer to this, its `NULL`.

Now again, when you make this assignment:

```
startPointer =  (Msg *)RxBufferArray[trackSN].IntMsg;
```

The typecasting among different structures should be handled carefully. the startPointer->pMessage just looks at `Memory address + sizeof(UINT)` of RxBufferArray[trackSN] which is probably `0x8` and as this memory is not accessible because its not initialized, you see the error **cannot access memory at address 0x8**

Comment: Could you possibly suggest the changes? Unsure how to initialize and where to.